# Using the text_field_tag helper in a rails .html.erb file to make an ajax GET request with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

how do I use the form_tag and text_field_tag helpers in a .html.erb file to send an ajax GET request to a url and use the text_field's contents as params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails 3 one would use the standard [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) `form_for` with options `:remote => true`

```
<%= form_for(@article, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:content) %>
  <!-- or -->
  <%= text_field_tag("article[content]", @article.content) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[FormTagHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) like `text_field_tag` provide a number of methods for creating form tags that doesn’t rely on form builder objects. Instead, you provide the names and values manually.